# JSON encode SQL query data issue

Tags: php, ajax, json

I can't see why this is returning empty square brackets. What I'm actually trying to do is update a div dynamically from a `href`.

```
<?php



$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","ee2800","secret","ee2800");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else{
    echo "connected";

}

 $select = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Songs');

 $rows=array();

 While($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
 {
  $rows[] = $row;   
 }

 echo json_encode($rows);


?>
```

Comment: What do you see if you var_dump($rows)?

Comment: var dump returns

array(0) { }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but i can't see why this is returning empty square brackets

Because you are using

```
mysqli_connect
```

with

```
mysql_query
```

Hence no data to encode and empty array gives you your empty square brackets :) You can't mix those two APIs. Use **[MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli_query)** throughout if you connect using MySQLi. And when you are already doing some error checking on connection, why not do it for query result as well?

Comment: thanks, but it seems my array is empty (which i can't understand) but i have changed to mysqli :)

Comment: Array is empty because your query failed to execute and no data was returned, and your query failed to execute because of what's mentioned in this answer

Comment: not sure the best way of showing on this site, but i have changed all the mysql's to mysqli's and theres no change in the array being empty.

Comment: Just changing the spelling doesn't matter. Please have a look at the link I provided in my answer to know what parameters does mysqli expect.

Comment: Great, don't be sorry. I could have added the required code for you but the real purpose here is for the OP to learn what their mistake is and to code towards a solution with some assistance from others. Now you've learnt something new which will always help you with or without someone's help :)